# There is an ansi version of StrToInt?

Tags: delphi

It seems there is no Ansi overload for StrToInt. Is this right? Or maybe I am missing something. 
StrToInt insists to convert my ansistrings to string.

Comment: You could try the FastCoder's asm implementation. See http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/challenge_content/rtl_replcmnt_pkg.html and the FastCodeStrToInt32Unit.pas file. Change String type to AnsiString.

Comment: shlwapi.StrToIntA does not seem to call StrToIntW or StrToIntExW. Can't know about the performance though..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. There is no ANSI version of `StrToInt`. The place to find ANSI versions of standard function is the `AnsiStrings` unit, and there's nothing there.

Either write your own function to do the job, or accept the conversion required to use `StrToInt`.

It's not too hard to write your own function. It might look like this:

```
uses 
  SysConst; // for SInvalidInteger
....
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
function AnsiStrToInt(const s: AnsiString): Integer;

  procedure Error;
  begin
    raise EConvertError.CreateResFmt(@SInvalidInteger, [s]);
  end;

var
  Index, Len, Digit: Integer;
  Negative: Boolean;
begin
  Index := 1;
  Result := 0;
  Negative := False;
  Len := Length(s);
  while (Index <= Len) and (s[Index] = ' ') do
    inc(Index);
  if Index > Len then
    Error;
  case s[Index] of
  '-','+':
    begin
      Negative := s[Index] = '-';
      inc(Index);
      if Index > Len then
        Error;
    end;
  end;
  while Index <= Len do
  begin
    Digit := ord(s[Index]) - ord('0');
    if (Digit < 0) or (Digit > 9) then
      Error;
    Result := Result * 10 + Digit;
    if Result < 0 then
      Error;
    inc(Index);
  end;
  if Negative then
    Result := -Result;
end;
```

This is a cut-down version of that found in `StrToInt`. It does not handle hexadecimal and is a bit more stringent regarding errors. Before using this code I'd want to test whether or not this really is your bottleneck.

It is quite interesting that this code, based on that in the RTL source, is incapable of returning `low(Integer)`. It's not too hard to fix that up, but it would make the code more complex.

Comment: Damn it! I work with LARGE files. They are ANSI so I wanted to have my whole program work in 'ANSI mode' so save RAM (and CPU). The damn function will ruin everything. I could write my own function but it may not be as fast as Embarcadero's so I better stick with StrToInt then.

Comment: A call to StrToInt, converting one short string to UTF16 won't hurt. Where do LARGE files come into this? You cannot avoid UTF16 in modern Delphi. The RTL and VCL all use UTF16. What's more, what do you think happens when you pass an ANSI string to an ANSI Win32 function? Yup, it gets converted to UTF16. The overhead of a short lived temp string is not severe.

Comment: I have 20GB+ ASCII text files with billions of entries. Converting up and down from/to string/ansistring will ruin performance.

Comment: Also, if you want to write your own converter then that is quite easy. Use the code from pre Unicode Delphi. And really, is the perf of your program determined by calls to StrToInt? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Will perf be that bad. Surely your program is disk bound rather than CPU bound. Did you measure?

Comment: The program is doing complex computations on each text entry. So the disk is not the biggest problem. IF I am parsing the file without computations, then yes, the disk is the bottleneck, but when I enable the computations for each entry then everything depends on CPU.

Comment: @Altar: But you're only doing the StrToInt conversion once, right? So it's not the bottleneck. Disk I/O is going to be a much greater bottleneck than your computations.

Comment: One row has multiple numbers separated by ':'. I need to extract the numbers. Please remember that the file can have (fortunately, not always) up to 6.3 billion entries! So, I have to apply StrToInt multiple times on each entry. This is why I think I will stick with the ASM version of StrToInt (and accept the conversion from Ansi to String that it does).

Comment: Did you actually try to use a function like David wrote (I assume hex is not important for you, anway?) and actually profile which was faster, or if and where there is a bottleneck? If your computations are so complicated that disk I/O is not the bottleneck anymore, ISTM that converting the string may not be a bottleneck either.

Comment: @Altar If you really do have a bottleneck here then I am prepared to bet that it will be on the heap allocations. Splitting lines on separators into separate values causing a boat load of heap allocations. They will dominate perf by at least an order of magnitude over the text to int conversion. I do have a strong suspicion that you are not on top of the true perf bottleneck.

Comment: What you really need here is a function that takes a line as input and returns an array of values. Better still, you pass in a pre-allocated array, preferably on the stack if possible, and the function splits and populates in one go, without touching the heap. Remember that the heap is your friend when you want convenience, but your mortal enemy when you care about perf.

Comment: It should be easy to set up a unit perf test in a loop to generate strings and run them through the new vs. old function and see exactly how much this affects performance.

Comment: > takes a line as input and returns an array of values - Unfortunately, I also have strings. The format is like:  @xxx:77:88:99 xxx:9:0. But your idea is really good. I will try to see what I can do about it. Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If they are of that rigid form then you get the function to return a record with all the values in. Avoid heap allocation. But always, time, time, and time again. That's the most important.

Comment: I created a new topic about format of the line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245758/how-to-quickly-parse-an-ansi-atring

Answer (score 2):

The code is actually very simple (hex strings aren't supported but prolly you don't need them):

```
function AnsiStrToInt(const S: RawByteString): Integer;
var
  P: PByte;
  Negative: Boolean;
  Digit: Integer;

begin
  P:= Pointer(S);
// skip leading spaces
  while (P^ = Ord(' ')) do Inc(P);
  Negative:= False;
  if (P^ = Ord('-')) then begin
    Negative:= True;
    Inc(P);
  end
  else if (P^ = Ord('+')) then Inc(P);

  if P^ = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('No data');

  Result:= 0;
  repeat
    if Cardinal(Result) > Cardinal(High(Result) div 10) then
      raise Exception.Create('Integer overflow');
    Digit:= P^ - Ord('0');
    if (Digit < 0) or (Digit > 9) then
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid char');
    Result:= Result * 10 + Digit;
    if (Result < 0) then begin
      if not Negative or (Cardinal(Result) <> Cardinal(Low(Result))) then
        raise Exception.Create('Integer overflow');
    end;
    Inc(P);
  until (P^ = 0);
  if Negative then Result:= -Result;
end;
```

Comment: `Tmp < 0` is probably more efficient. Or assign `Result * 10 + Digit` directly to `Result` and check for `< 0`. Interestingly the entire approach means that the function is incapable of returning `low(Integer)`. I guess it would need to use different branches for +ve and -ve to be able to return `low(Integer)`.

Comment: Nah, actually the second idea was a mistake, I deleted it; the counterexample is `9999999999`.

Comment: I fixed the case of `Low(Integer)`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because `if Negative then Result:= -Result;` looks like it cannot yield `low(Integer)`. That's because `abs(low(Integer)) = abs(high(Integer)) + 1`

Comment: try `Writeln(AnsiStrToInt(IntToStr(Low(Integer))));`

Comment: I'm not running any code here. Just reading it. More fun that way. So what integer value x is such that -x equals low(Integer)? What am I missing?

Comment: also for the sake of full disclosure the code should be compiled with {$Q-} option but this is the default option, no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tip:

[How to convert AnsiString to UnicodeString in Delphi XE4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880132/how-to-convert-ansistring-to-unicodestring-in-delphi-xe4)

Example:

```
var
  a : AnsiString;
  b : String;
  c : Integer;
begin
  a := '123';
  b := String(a);
  c := StrToInt(b);
```

Comment: Not really an answer to what was discussed here. See Davids answer for details.