# How to quickly parse an ANSI string?

Tags: delphi

I have a large ansi text file. The file contains many entries (millions to billions). Each entry has 4 lines like this:

```
@Instrument:6:73:941:1973#0/1  <---- I need the content of this line 
other stuff2
other stuff3
other stuff4
```

I need the content of the first line in a record like:

```
   TYPE
      RBlock= record  // @Instrument:6:73:941:1973#0/1
       Instrument: String;  // Instrument
       Lane: Integer; // 6  
       TileNo: Integer;  // 73
       X: integer;  // 941
       Y: Integer;  // 1973   THIS COULD BE SLOW!
       ID: AnsiString;  // #0  
      end;
```

I am afraid that using `StrToInto` to convert the text to integer may be slow because it first converts the `AnsiString` to string.

Any ideas on how could I read it faster will be appreciated.

Update: the line could also have an alternative format: `@Instrument:136:FC6:2:2104:15343:197393 1:Y:18:TACA`

Comment: I'm sure that using the code from your previous question, you can knock up a function to make one of these records with only a pair of heap allocations for the two strings.

Comment: Talk about bottlenecks! StringReplace is very likely one of them.

Comment: And if you have made something working maybe it's worth putting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RudyVelthuis-You are right. I use not ReplaceChar instead of ReplaceString and it is indeed much faster. Thanks.

Comment: In which variables would the values from alternate format end up? Another question, is it possible to have negative values or only positive values?

Comment: Wouldn't the best bet be to parse a small subset of the data using the simplest approach first? Extrapolate from that and see if the performance is acceptable. If not, profile and find the bottlenecks. It's only at that point that I feel there'd be a need to start asking questions here.

Comment: Are you certain the bottleneck is in parsing the input, and not in storing the result?  How are you storing/using your RBlock Records in memory?  If you store them in a Dynamic Array, there are numerous tricks you can use to ensure cache-efficiency.  Even if you simply write them to a database as you create them, you can gain speed by batching them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to examine your data and check what sort of data could occur. Personally I would probably do something like this (for the first example):

```
procedure ParseLine(const aLine: RawByteString; var aInstrument: string; var
    aLane, aTileNo, aX, aY: Integer; var aMultiplexID: Ansistring; var aPair:
    Byte);
var
  arrayIndex: Integer;
  index: Integer;
  lineLength: Integer;
  NumList: array[0..3] of Integer;
  I: Integer;
  multiEnd: Integer;
begin
  lineLength := Length(aLine);
  // Get the aInstrument
  index := Pos(':', aLine);
  SetLength(aInstrument, index - 2);
  for I := 2 to index - 1 do
    aInstrument[I-1] := Char(aLine[I]);
  // Get the integers
  arrayIndex := 0;
  FillMemory(@NumList, SizeOf(NumList), 0);
  while (index < lineLength) and (arrayIndex < 4) do
  begin
    Inc(index);
    if (aLine[index] = ':') or (aLine[index] = '#') then
      Inc(arrayIndex)
    else
      NumList[arrayIndex] := NumList[arrayIndex] * 10 + Ord(aLine[index]) - Ord('0');
  end;
  aLane := NumList[0];
  aTileNo := NumList[1];
  aX := NumList[2];
  aY := NumList[3];
  // Get the Multiplex
  multiEnd := Pos('/', aLine, index);
  SetLength(aMultiplexID, multiEnd - index - 1);
  Inc(index);
  for I := index to multiEnd - 1 do
    aMultiplexID[I-index+1] := aLine[I];
  // Get the aPair
  if (multiEnd+1 < lineLength) then
    aPair := Ord(aLine[multiEnd+1]) - Ord('0')
  else
    aPair := 0;
end;
```

This could be optimized more but that would start to really hit the readability. The issue here is going to be whether the data is valid for this routine. It will handle a string that's too short but not invalid values in the text although it won't return an error when it's too short. Negative numeric's would also be a problem. What you need to look at is your data, what it looks like, what the chance of corruptions or invalid data would be and also how important speed is to you. It's a balancing act. You could remove all of the checks and have it faster or add a lot more checks which would slow it down.

Comment: That's one approach. It may or may not be the fastest for his data sample without further testing.

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++ there's a function called sscanf() for stuff like this.

I've seen a couple of implementations of it for Delphi.  Search using Google, as they don't like you posting links to external stuff here, and it seems silly to post all of the source code for an entire freaking library function rather than simply a link to it as a reply.

You might also try using regular expressions to split the strings into pieces.

I'm not sure how these would compare with the string functions mentioned here in terms of performance, but they're worth considering.

(TIP: You're going to get the best performance by writing a short parser specifically designed for these strings.)

Comment: -1 for advising the usage of regular expressions to parse data from known and unchanging source format.

Comment: -1. The complaint was "poor performance of string parsing code", and your recommendation was *regular expressions*? (Your "TIP" is also pretty meaningless, as that was the entire subject of the question: "I need a custom parser for these strings". "Ok. TIP: You'll get the  best performance by writing a short parser for these strings.".

Comment: "Any ideas on how could I read it faster will be appreciated." Some Regular expression libraries (eg., TRegExp) pre-compile the pattern and generate an internal map that can often run faster than brute-force blind string search-and-replace algorithms. I used to write code that searched for common subexpressions in humonguous files containing tens of megabytes of genomic data. When you're working with huge datasets like this, you cannot rely on your intuition. Your results can be very sensitive to not only the algorithm but the patterns of data you're searching through.

Comment: Actually a compiled regex can be very performant

Comment: Why does this contain net down-votes? I think it's an excellent question about a topic that's often not given enough respectful discussion. It's obvious that some of the answers here are not based on much experience with processing huge chunks of string data that require some modicum of non-trivial parsing. Anybody who's ever spent any time developing import routines for genetic and genomic data knows it's folly to pre-judge the performance of any given string processing approaches for parsing because most of the time the performance is unpredictable without a huge amount of pre-analysis!